# Quantum Amplitude Estimation formulations (Brassard et. al. vs Montanaro)

Tags: grovers-algorithm, amplitude-amplification

I am puzzled on the relation between the two approaches (old and new).

**(a)** The original approach of QAE as described by [Brassard et. al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0005055) uses two operators to form ${Q}$:
$$
{Q}={A} {S}_0 {A}^{\dagger} {S}_{\psi_0},
$$
where
$S_0 = \mathbb{I}_{n+1}-2|0\rangle\left\langle\left. 0\right|_{n+1}\right.$ and ${S}_{\psi_0}=\mathbb{I}_{n+1}-2 | \psi_0 \rangle|0\rangle \langle\psi_0|\langle 0|$ are reflections and $\mathbb{I}_{n+1}$ is the identity operator on $n+1$ qubits.

**(b)** On the other hand, using [Montanaro's approach](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.06987) we use a seemingly different set of operators:
$$
G = (\mathbb{I}_{n-k} \otimes W)(A \otimes \mathbb{I}_{k})
$$
where $A|0\rangle^{\otimes n} = \sum_{i \in \{0,1 \}^k} a_i |\psi_i\rangle|i\rangle$, and $W|x \rangle |0 \rangle = |x\rangle\Big(\sqrt{1-f(x)}|0\rangle +\sqrt{f(x)}|1\rangle\Big).$

**Both** are then applied several times to amplify the "marked" amplitude and then measure. However, I think I miss something in the sense that its not obvious that the function $f$ is encoded in the former and I cannot clearly see how one is related to the other.

I would like to understand if using some transformations I can move either way.